# Swift 2 String & NSURL Errors

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2

Upon updating to Swift2 I am receiving a few errors that I don't understand:

**First Error:**

```
 if(!parole1.text.isEmpty && !parole2.text.isEmpty && !parole3.text.isEmpty && isValidEmail(parole4.text)){

... code
            }

--> ERROR: *Value of optional type String? not unwrapped!*
```

**Second Error:**

```
var dataString = "name="+name.text+"&name2="+Name2.text+"&parola="+parola.text+"&pwd="+pwd.text

--> ERROR: *Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time*
```

**Third Error:**

```
let reply = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response, error:&error)

-->ERROR: *Extra argument 'error' in call*
```

Answer (score 2):

**First error:**

parole1.text is an optional and has to be unpacked with ? or ! before you can call isEmpty on it.

**Second error:**

I'm not sure why this is an issue for swift but it's solvable with a formated string like this:

```
var dataString = "name=\(name.text)&name2=\(Name2.text)&parola=\(parola.text)&pwd=\(pwd.text)"
```

However you problaby want to unpack the text here as well with either a `if let` or a hard `!`

**Third error:**

NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest doesn't take an error as a parameter any more.

```
do {
   let reply = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response)
} catch {

}
```

Edit: use `NSURLSession` instead. `NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest` is deprecated

Comment: The second error is almost certainly because the variables are not unwrapped. I think the problem is that the compiler has trouble doing the type inference.

Comment: NSURLConnection is deprecated after IOS9. Consider moving to NSURLSession.